# Does having authenticator app/OTP generator built into Password Manager defeat its purpose?

Tags: password-management, multi-factor, one-time-password

For example the KeepassOTP plugin is one of a few plugins for Keepass, that allows users to view their OTP code from within the password manager itself. Does this defeat the purpose of having a OTP as a form of 2FA? If the database is compromised now the attacker has both the OTPs and password. Isn't the point of using 2FA to prevent this? With this specific plugin the OTPs are actually stored in a separate database with its own master password. Does that actually make a difference since two passwords are no better than one complex one? What if the authentication app is on a different device (such as a smartphone) then would it requiring a password increase security?

Do OTPs and passwords really count as a form of 2FA since they are both things you know?

Comment: It depends on your threat model. Compromising the DB is not the only way in which someone can get your password. They might obtain it via shouldersurfing, or by phishing, or maybe you used it on a different site that has a bad hashing algorithm or none at all. In all these cases the 2FA inside the password manager wouldn't be compromised. Note that for most situations compromise of the password database is a very remote possibility. It's much more likely to be phished using a clone website.